# Pandas backfilling values based on a datetime index and a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Pandas` data frame with two sets of dates, a `DatetimeIndex`for the index and a column named `date2` containing datetime objects, a value and an id. For some id's I am missing values where `date2` is equal to the index, in this case I want to fill the row/values with the values of the previous DatetimeIndex and id's values. The `date1` represents the current point in time, and `date2` represents the last date. Each `df[df.id == id]` can be treated as its own dataframe however the data is stored in one giant dataframe 500k rows.

**Example: Given**

```
            date2      id   value
index
2006-01-24  2006-01-26  3   3       
2006-01-25  2006-01-26  1   1
2006-01-25  2006-01-26  2   2
2006-01-26  2006-01-26  2   2.1
2006-01-27  2006-02-26  4   4
```

In this example, were missing a `index == date2` row for id 1, id 2 and for id3. I'd like to backfill each missing row with the previous index value respective to it's id.

**I'd like to return:**

```
            date2      id   value
index
2006-01-24  2006-01-26  3   3               
2006-01-25  2006-01-26  1   1
2006-01-25  2006-01-26  2   2
2006-01-26  2006-01-26  1   1    #<---- row added
2006-01-26  2006-01-26  2   2.1
2006-01-26  2006-01-26  3   3    #<---- row added
2006-01-27  2006-02-26  4   4
2006-02-26  2006-02-26  4   4    #<---- row added
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic on the basis of which  you are adding the new row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly reluctant to answer b/c it seems @chrisb may have successfully answered the original question, which later changed.  However, Chris hasn't updated the answer in a few days and this answer does take a different approach so I'm going to +1 Chris's answer and add this one.

First, just create a new dataframe from the original with 'index'='date2'.  This will be the basis for appending to the existing dataframe (note that 'index' is a column here, not an index):

```
df2 = df[ df['index'] != df['date2'] ]
df2['index'] = df2['date2']
df2['value'] = np.nan

        index       date2  id  value
0  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   3    NaN
1  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   1    NaN
2  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   2    NaN
4  2006-02-26  2006-02-26   4    NaN
```

Now, just append all of these, but drop the ones we don't need (if we already have an existing row with 'index'='date2', as for id=2 here):

```
df3 = df.append(df2)
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates(['index','date2','id'])
df3 = df3.reset_index(drop=True).sort(['id','index','date2'])
df3['value'] = df3.value.fillna(method='ffill')

        index       date2  id  value
1  2006-01-25  2006-01-26   1    1.0
6  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   1    1.0
2  2006-01-25  2006-01-26   2    2.0
3  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   2    2.1
0  2006-01-24  2006-01-26   3    3.0
5  2006-01-26  2006-01-26   3    3.0
4  2006-01-27  2006-02-26   4    4.0
7  2006-02-26  2006-02-26   4    4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't very clean, but is a possible solution.  First, I moved the index into a column, `date1`:

```
In [228]: df
Out[228]: 
       date1      date2  id  value
0 2006-01-24 2006-01-26   3    3.0
1 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   1    1.0
2 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   2    2.0
3 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   2    2.1
```

Then I grouped by each pair of dates, adding ids to those pairs that match.  This involves breaking the DataFrame into a list of subframes and use `concat` to stick back together.

```
In [229]: dfs = []
     ...: for (date1, date2), df_gb in df.groupby(['date1','date2']):
     ...:     if date1 == date2:
     ...:         to_add = list(set([1,2,3]) - set(df_gb['id']))
     ...:         df_gb = df_gb.append(pd.DataFrame({'id': to_add, 'date1': date1, 'date2': date2, 'value': np.nan}), ignore_index=True)
     ...:     dfs.append(df_gb)

In [231]: df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)

In [232]: df
Out[232]: 
       date1      date2  id  value
0 2006-01-24 2006-01-26   3    3.0
1 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   1    1.0
2 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   2    2.0
3 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   2    2.1
4 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   1    NaN
5 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   3    NaN
```

Finally, I sorted and filled the missing values.

```
In [233]: df = df.sort(['id', 'date1', 'date2'])

In [234]: df = df.fillna(method='ffill')

In [236]: df.sort(['date1', 'date2'])
Out[236]: 
       date1      date2  id  value
0 2006-01-24 2006-01-26   3    3.0
1 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   1    1.0
2 2006-01-25 2006-01-26   2    2.0
4 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   1    1.0
3 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   2    2.1
5 2006-01-26 2006-01-26   3    3.0
```

Comment: Arg! thanks but just found an edge case in this, I'll update my question this is close thou.

Comment: Essentially if i have multiple date2 values for the entire set, and only one date2 value for id 1, I get a value for every date2 for id 1 now.